# Why would the JQuery Post and Get methods do nothing when they are called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, get

I am currently working on a website which requires one page on the website to open others using the post method through a script, i.e., without direct user input. I have attempted to use the JQuery post method, but can get no results.

In order to test the code I have attempted to run the post method in its simplest form, with only a URI, attempting to open various web pages, but so far nothing has happened.

I have confirmed that the JQuery script is running (hence the 'alert' function) so the problem must be with the post method. I have researched this problem exhaustively both on stackoverflow and on other sites, even copying and attempting the run numerous samples of code, but have found nothing helpful. I have not under any circumstances observed either the get or post method functioning at all.

When I first had this problem I was on a Linux machine; I have attempted to repeat my experiments on Windows without success. I have attached my full test code, both html and javascript, below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    alert("The Button was Clicked.")
        $.post("http://www.spacex.com/");
    });
});
</script>

<body>
<h2>Web Page </h2>
<p>Click the Button to Open the Website </p>
<button>Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$.post` and `$.get` make AJAX calls. They don't change the current page.

Comment: The requirement to open a new page via post and a script seems a bit strange, can you elaborate on why.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either read the response into a callback function.

```
$.post("ajax/test.html", function(data) {
  $(".result").html(data);
});
```

Or if you want to call the page directly, setup a regular form in your page and use jquery to submit it.

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $("#targetform").submit();
 });
```

Or even simpler still, just submit the form in the old fashioned way with a form action and submit button, no JQuery required.

Comment: I'd give you bonus points for mentioning the obvious of actually submitting a form.